# SQL to find elements NOT IN a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find elements in a set which are *not* in customers table. Here's an example table:

```
customer_id | customer_name
1             joe smith
2             john doe
3             jane doe
```

Here's an example set:

```
('joe smith', 'pepi fogelhut', 'jane doe', 'smiley whiplash')
```

The output of the query for this data should be:

```
pepi fogelhut
smiley whiplash
```

I'm pretty sure i need to use a left join. Something like this?

```
select customer_name as n1 from customers as c1 left outer join customers as c2 on n1=c2.customer_name
```

Comment: Where does the dataset come from?

Comment: The data above is complete bogus. The real data comes from data entry employees. Why?

Comment: I think he's asking because this is a lot easier if your data set is stored in a column of another table.

Comment: Because you cannot compare an array with a stored list in this way. Either store the array, and run the comparison in MySQL, or convert the list to an array and run the comparison in your application level code.

Comment: OK. So let's assume I put the 2nd set of data into another table, damn why can't i press enter

Comment: Then simply (left) outer join the first table onto the second table, selecting only those results where first_table.customer_id IS NULL;

Answer (score 2):

If you put the data into a temporary table, you can simple select all values from the table that do NOT appear in your original table. Something like:

```
SELECT name FROM temporaryTable WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM customerTable);
```

this will return you any customer name that is IN the temporary table but not in your original customer table.